# Postflop play books references

Tags: poker-theory, strategy

I feel quite comfortable playing pre flop, but I feel that I am weak in post flop play. I lack the big picture of post flop play.

Can anyone give me a good reference for post flop play?

Comment: Usually a good book will pull together the concepts of both Pre and Post flop play in a coherent way, so take a look at the suggestions at [Classic Books for Texas Hold'Em](http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/472/88) for a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

As well as the link Toby has suggested above take a look a the following:

- [the simple psychology of postflop play](http://www.pokerlistings.com/strategy/the-simple-psychology-of-postflop-play)
- [How to play after the flop](http://www.pokerstrategy.com/strategy/sng/1349/1/)
- [Post flop strategy](http://www.pokersavvy.com/Texas-holdem/post-flop-strategy.html)
- [Post flop play after missing flop](http://www.learn-texas-holdem.com/questions/postflop-play-after-missing-flop.htm)
- [Top 15 Poker - Post Flop strategy](http://www.top15poker.com/Strategy/Post_Flop_Strategy.htm)
- [Partypoker - Post flop play](http://www.partypoker.com/how-to-play/new-to-the-game/how-a-hand-plays-out/post-flop-play.html)
- [Pokerstars Pokerschool - Post Flop quiz](http://www.pokerschoolonline.com/articles/Post-Flop-Play)

The last one is a quiz. There are a lot of useful quizzes on this site. If you dont already have an account I would recommend that you sign up and give some of them a go.

Hope some of these links are useful

Answer (score 1):

No Limit Hold'em Theory and Practice is the textbook on this subject, and it would be the place I would start reading first.