# What are best books for newbie, medium and advanced level players in order to learn no limit Texas Hold'em?

Tags: books, learning

There are too much books about no limit Texas Hold'em. One can not read them all. There are some good books in  [this question.](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/472/classic-books-for-texas-holdem) I would like to know more specific about which of them are good for absolut newbie, which are good for medium level player and which are targeting more advanced players.

Please post a list of reccomended literature for those levels ( newbie, medium, advanced l) of players.

Comment: This question was formed by dividing the original http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/what-are-best-books-programes-and-sites-to-improve-texas-holdem-limit-and-no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best books for novice is basically anything from David Sklansky, especially "No Limit Hold 'em: Theory and Practice"

As you get more advanced, you need to tailor the sources you read to game you play. If you play SNG, then you need to read about SNG. Collin Moshman wrote rally great books covering SNG and heads up situation.

If you play tournaments, you need to read literature related to tournaments play. I think of Gus Hansen, but I am really not a tournament player.

There is also a lot of literature covering psychological part of poker and long term decision(what stakes to play, bankroll management, multitabling...).

In my opinion, strictly dissecting books into skill levels categories is not a good practice. Every book covers a little bit different topics from different point of view. I think that the content of books is really well described in the question you refer and no one can give you much more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two good books geared towards newer players not mentioned in the other question are:

[Poker Made Math Easy by Owen "QTip" Gaines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/061539745X)

This book covers how to do EV calcs in a gentle yet comprehensive way.

[Hole Card Confessions by Owen "QTip" Gaines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005KNGUGK)

How to read players and adjust.

The two books taken together form a very good course in NLHE for the serious beginner or amateur player.  Both books include short quizzes after each chapter to ensure comprehension.

My all-time favorite poker book though is:

[Easy Game by Andrew "BalugaWhale" Seidman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/146641197X)

More advanced thoughts by a long time successful player.  His videos on Deuces Cracked are excellent too.